# How to find a cell in one of thee non-adjacent columns and return the row number - Excel Formula needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have numbers in columns A, F and K. I have to find given number and return row number. Numbers are kind of IDs, they will not repeat. I know how to do it with VBA, but I was asked to use only formulas and I got stuck. Current solution was working for two columns, I need to modify it to work for 3: `=IFERROR(MATCH([@NumberToFind],Sheet1!A:A,0),MATCH([@NumberToFind],Sheet1!F:F,0))`

[@NumberToFind] is the name of the column with numbers which I'm looking for in Sheet1

I'm not good with formulas, I was looking for a solution, but I think I'm asking the wrong question to Google. All I found is how to search in multiple columns, if I want to use them as multiple criteria.

It looks like this:

| row 1: | Column A | (...) | Column F | (...) | Column K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row 2: | 1 |  | 4 |  | 7 |
| row 3: | 2 |  | 5 |  | 8 |
| row 4: | 3 |  | 6 |  | 9 |

And in Sheet2 they want to look for nr 1  and answer will be 2 (because it's in row 2). If they ask for nr 8 answer will be 3 (because it's in row 3)

Comment: You are going to use the rownumber in another formula?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a representative data sample, along with expected output, so we can test proposed solutions.

Comment: Yes, they want to use it later for something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=MATCH(1,([@NumberToFind]=Sheet1!A:A)+([@NumberToFind]=Sheet1!F:F)+([@NumberToFind]=Sheet1!K:K),0)`

Depending the version of your Excel you may need to enter the formula with `ctrl + shift + enter`

You can use `MATCH(1,(condition1)+(condition2)+(condition3),0)`
Where `1` is to be read as TRUE and `+` as OR. The conditions will result in arrays of `0`'s (result of condition is FALSE) and `1`'s (result of condition is TRUE). If there are more matches it returns the row # of the first matching row only, but that's not the case in your data.

Comment: Typically this will be combined with `INDEX`, for instance if you want the result to be the value of Sheet1 column P in the row found from the formula above, then use: `=INDEX(Sheet1!P:P,MATCH(1;([@NumberToFind]=Sheet1!A:A)+([@NumberToFind]=Sheet1!F:F)+([@NumberToFind]=Sheet1!K:K),0))`

Comment: It worked! I only had to change ; to ,  a typo I guess?
`=MATCH(1,([@NumberToFind]=Sheet1!A:A)+([@NumberToFind]=Sheet1!F:F)+([@NumberToFind]=Sheet1!K:K),0)`
Thank you! :D

Comment: Yes, I use dutch excel version on my phone and don't know how to change the language. In Dutch the formula separator is `;` by default. I accidentally must've typed one on auto-pilot mode when I answered and overlooked it. Glad it works. Changed it in my answer.  Please look in my comment below the answer too. My guess is that it would be of use for you as well.

Comment: You need to replace the `;` there still. I can't edit that comment anymore.